# What are correct tags or SE sites for the I2P questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-rec

Are proper tags or SE sites for [the I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/) questions?
I find out some specific links maybe clarify some things about  what is the I2P:
[I2P Compared to Tor](https://geti2p.net/en/comparison/tor) and 
[The I2P are the main alternatives to the Tor](https://blog.torproject.org/comment/270620#comment-270620)

For example:
What do the "Delay Connect" mean on i2p's "Edit proxy settings" page?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking, "*What* are the [correct] tags *to use* for I2P questions, *or which SE site should they be posted on*?"

Comment: Seems on topic. I guess the big question is is i2p unambiguous enough to be a good tag and who will write the tag wiki

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I think you have the same mean to me and I have reworded this meta question to try to clear.

Answer (score 3):

Tags need to be created by someone - usually after a question is created.

I guess the smart thing to do is to ask a question, making it unambiguous to what i2p is. Make sure folks with enough reputation know (but you have!). Include other, appropriate tags and once the i2p tag is created, help fill in the tag wiki - try not to copy sources but paraphrase and refine to fit our needs better.

Folks will help, just get the ball rolling.

Comment: "making it unambiguous to what i2p is", Is I put the i2p project home page is enough?

Comment: Personally I'd make it a little clear what it is, and that it's something you run on a PC, just to be safe.

Comment: I reword this question by finding out two links to try to clarify what is the I2P.

Comment: I have some difficulty to understand your meaning, Are you meaning I just post my example question and wait peoples help create/select correct tags is enough?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean